# Accessing memory pointed to by PAnsiChar in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: winapi, inno-setup, pascalscript, cryptoapi

Need to Use the Win32 encryption API to convert password to encrypted blob before passing to child process.

Trying to use `CryptProtectData@crypt32.dll` API to perform the encryption.
The function is returning success. But I'm facing issue while accessing the returned encrypted blob.

Tried to use the `StrPas()` to convert the `PAnsiChar` to `AnsiString`, but I get *"Invalid identifier"* error.

```pascal
const
  CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE = $4;

type
  DataBlob = record
    cbData: Longword;
    pbData: PAnsiChar;
  end;

function CryptProtectData(var pDataIn: DataBlob;
  szDataDescr, pOptionalEntropy, pvReserved, pPromptStruct : DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD; var pDataOut: DataBlob): Boolean;
  external 'CryptProtectData@crypt32.dll stdcall delayload';

var
  Password: AnsiString;

function Encrypt(): Boolean;
var
  DataBlobIn, DataBlobOut: DataBlob
  EncryptStr: AnsiString;
begin
  DataBlobIn.cbData := Length(Password);
  DataBlobIn.pbData := Password;
  if CryptProtectData(DataBlobIn, 0, 0, 0, 0, CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE, DataBlobOut) then
  begin
    Log('Success');

    { Using StrPas gives an 'unknown identifier error' }
    EncryptStr := StrPas(DataBlobOut.pbData);
  end;
end;
```

The size of the return memory blob is `DataBlobOut.cbData`, 
but how to access the memory blob returned in `DataBlobOut.pbData`?

Can you please point to some sample code where we can access the memory of length X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy data from a memory pointer to an Inno Setup buffer-like variable (such as `AnsiString`), you can use [`RtlMoveMemory` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlmovememory):

```pascal
procedure RtlMoveMemory(Dest: AnsiString; Source: PAnsiChar; Len: Integer);
  external 'RtlMoveMemory@kernel32.dll stdcall';
```

You can use it like:

```pascal
// Allocate memory
SetLength(EncryptStr, DataBlobOut.cbData);
// Copy data
RtlMoveMemory(EncryptStr, DataBlobOut.pbData, DataBlobOut.cbData);
```